# Does COPY FROM write to transaction log?

Tags: postgresql, replication, bulk-load, wal

In postgres 9.3, the `COPY FROM ... STDIN;` command is by far the quickest way to insert bulk data.  Does this come at the cost of not writing these inserted rows to the transaction log?  We're using Write-Ahead Logging to update secondary servers so it is important that it does.

Comment: I have no firsthand experience with this, but my experience with Postgres in general tells me that they would certainly mention a limitation like this in the `COPY` documentation. There is such a limitation with `hash` indexes, and the docs come with a very clear warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COPY` most certainly does write to WAL (unless you're `COPY`ing to an `UNLOGGED` or `TEMPORARY` table, of course).

Data loaded with `COPY` gets replicated normally.

About the only thing you can do that *isn't* properly replicated is write to a hash index, and the documentation for those is covered in warnings. Personally I'd like to just remove that feature.